# How did Celine Dion learn to sing in perfect English?

Tags: english, native-language, informal-learning

[Celine Dion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celine_Dion) is from Quebec, a predominantly French-speaking province in Canada. English is not her native language, yet in her songs her English is perfect. Is this because she grew up speaking the language or some kind of language training?

Comment: Welcome to Language Learning.SE! This question seems to be too broad since it asks about an open set of factors that affected an undefined group of people. There can be literally a million of different reasons, including that quite often, even the people who never speak a word in English can memorize the lyrics of a certain song so that it *looked* like they have no accent at all.

Comment: We do have questions such as [How did Cardinal Mezzofanti learn foreign languages?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/2282/800), so it should be possible to rephrase your question in a way that makes it acceptable for this site. For example, how did Celine Dion learn to speak English without an accent?

Comment: A general question about famous pop singers would not be self-evidently out of scope, I think.

Comment: Canada is a bilingual country and even in Quebec there is some exposure to English language, and it is certainly part of the curriculum at school.

Answer (score 2):

In 1989, Céline Dion was sent to École Berlitz to work on her English. Also, she has written quite a few albums in English, that must definitely have improved her accent!